# Eclipse deleted my project on import

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just imported an Android Project into Eclipse, the project was located in the workspace.

After import, every file content went blank, there is no code. What happened, and how can I get my code back?

Comment: I have seen a similar issue before - are you loading your project in a Linux environment?  If so, the issue may be folder capitalization.

Comment: no it's windows. I checked the files myself using notepad and they are all blank, are they overwritten?